Is It necessary for a monopoly firm to be profitable at the elastic region of the demand curve?
Considering a linear demand curve, we conclude that the monopolist only produces at the elastic region of the demand curve (given, he doesn't discriminate prices). But if the cost is a function of quantity produced and increases rapidly due to increase in Q, then the monopolist may incur losses even at the elastic region, wouldn't he?

The question in the title is different from the question in the body.


the monopolist only produces at the elastic region ... But ...  the monopolist may incur losses even at the elastic region

There is no contradiction here. If I like chocolate cake it does not mean that I like all cake; if the profit maximizing quantity is in the elastic region it does not mean that all quantities in the elastic region are profit maximizing or even profitable.
An example
Let $D(p) = 3 - p$ so $MR(q) = 3 - 2q$, and let
$$
C(q) = \frac{q^{100}}{100}
$$
so $MC(q) = q^{99}$.
The profit maximizing quantity is $q = 1$, at this point $MR(1) = MC(1)$. The elastic region is $[0,1.5]$, but at $q=1.1$ the monopolist is already making heavy losses, around $-135.716$ according to this C++ program.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
  float q = 1.1;
  double result = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i<100; i++)
  {
     result *= q;
  }
  result = (3-q)*q - result/100;
  cout << result;
  return 0;
}


Yes. Was thinking about a similar model but wasn't sure, Thanks
